# Como eu posso pegar o numero do Índice de um Array?

Tags: javascript, array, objetos, indexof

Como eu posso adquirir o numero dos elementos que tem o valor de `day` de 5. Isso teria que me retornar outro Array, para a manipulação ficar mais dinâmica.

Esse é o Array que tenho de base:

```
let arr = [ 
   {name: "Salário", amount: 150000, day: 5},
   {name: "Internet", amount: -11590, day: 10},
   {name: "Teste", amount: 15000, day: 5},
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando o método `reduce`, você retorna um array com os index que tem o `day` igual a `5`. Fazemos uma verificação com `if (obj.day === 5)`, temos o código abaixo:

```js
let arr = [ 
   {name: "Salário", amount: 150000, day: 5},
   {name: "Internet", amount: -11590, day: 10},
   {name: "Teste", amount: 15000, day: 5},
];

const indexOfFive = arr.reduce(function(acc, obj, index) {
    if (obj.day === 5)
        acc.push(index);

    return acc;
}, []);

console.log('Posições que tem o day igual a 5: ', indexOfFive);
```

<sub>Para reaproveitar código, o `reduce` deveria estar dentro de uma função.</sub>

Comment: uma dúvida, o reduce vai percorrer todos os elementos, mesmo que encontro no primeiro certo?

Comment: @RicardoPontual isso mesmo. Não era essa o requisito da questao? _"Eu preciso saber a posição ou index, dos elementos que tem o valor do day: 5"_ , então são varios indices

Comment: tem razão eu não me atentei nisso, vou remover a resposta pq fica sem sentido

Answer (score 0):

Com [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) construa um [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) com os índices dos elementos de `arr` cujo o valor da propriedade `day` seja igual a `5` e para os outros valores complete com `null`. Do array resultante remova as entradas `null` com [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro).

```js
let arr = [ 
   {name: "Salário", amount: 150000, day: 5},
   {name: "Internet", amount: -11590, day: 10},
   {name: "Teste", amount: 15000, day: 5},
]

console.log(
   arr.map((e, i) => (e.day == 5)? i: null)     //Cria um array com os índices dos elementos 
                                                //cujo day == 5 e null para os demais.
      .filter(e=> e !== null)                   //Remove os nulls do resultado.
)
```

Comment: +1 Não sei porque o voto negativo! Está correto a resposta, pois era esse o resultado esperado.

Comment: @CmteCardeal, haters. Eu tenho aos montes.